Asp.net core 8 select multiple with default selected not working after upgrade
This code for select multiple with default selected options was working fine on .netcore 5 but after upgrade to .net 8 selected options not working
c# code
List<int> currentContentCatIDs = itemLoc.Content.ContentCategories.Where(x => x.Category.CatTypeId == 2).Select(a => a.CatId).ToList();
if (currentContentCatIDs != null && currentContentCatIDs.Count > 0)
{
    List<SelectListItem> catsSelectList = new();
    foreach (var instructorLoc in instructors)
        catsSelectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = instructorLoc.Title, Value = instructorLoc.CatId.ToString(), Selected = currentContentCatIDs.Contains(instructorLoc.CatId) });

    ViewBag.MultiInstructors = catsSelectList;
}
else
    ViewBag.MultiInstructors = new SelectList(instructors, "CatId", "Title", "");

view :
<select asp-for="InstructorsCatIDs" asp-items="ViewBag.MultiInstructors" class="select2 custom-select block" multiple="multiple"></select>

viewmodel :
public ContentCreateDto()
{
    InstructorsCatIDs = [];
}
public int[] InstructorsCatIDs { get; set; }

controller debug :

View file:

browser inspect :

no options included select on client side when inspecting elements, but on controller when debug the list of items includes the selected options

What's "not working" about it?  When you debug, what specifically fails?

no fails on debug, the object goes from controller to view throw viewbag with the selected options, but the options is not selected after run, same project works well on .net5 no code changes

When you debug, what is the resulting client-side markup for this <select> element?  Do any <option> elements in that markup include the selected attribute?  When you debug the server-side code, where you set that value: Selected = currentContentCatIDs.Contains(instructorLoc.CatId) - Do you observe that condition to be true for any of the records?  How have you confirmed these things?

no options included select on client side when inspecting elements, but on controller when debug the list of items includes the selected options

i will attach images to the question to describe that better

question updated with images

Would you please attach an image of selected options as well on you UI?

question updated

@AhmadAlaa: Out of curiosity, it may be worth checking the initial page source that the browser fetched from the server, as it may differ from the current DOM.  If the selected nature of the element(s) changed after loading the initial page source then the problem could be somewhere else entirely.  It could also be worth removing Select2 from the equation and re-testing, to see if that's related.  Etc.

I already did that before posting the question, and the rendered pure html is without selected, and please note that if i returned back to .net6 or 5 the same code will work

I tested with your codes and it work at myside for .net8, please check your page's script or else to see which modify the result. Test result.

the problem was on view model, i was initializing the array on constructor, question updated

The problem was on view model, i was initializing the array on constructor, i needed to remove this code from view model
InstructorsCatIDs = [];

